Family of closed sets from a countable space that contains all decreasing sequence intersections must have minimal set
Consider a second countable space $X$ and a family of closed sets from it $\mathcal F=\{K_\lambda\}$, such that for any decreasing sequence $K_1\supset K_2\supset\ldots$ it also contains the intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty K_n\in \mathcal F$. Then there must exist a minimal element $K\in\mathcal F$, i.e., such that $\nexists K'\in\mathcal F:K'\subsetneq K$.
Also, this question is tagged in the book as Brouwer's theorem, but I can't see why. Is this related to his famous fixed point theorem, or something else of him?

Have you tried showing that an arbitrary intersection of nested closed sets can be rewritten as a countable intersection, and then using Zorn's lemma?

@BrunoAndrades So, IIUC, by Zorn's lemma with the $\subset$ well-ordering and the intersection being an upper bound, there is a maximal element, which may well be $\emptyset$. Right? Actually, the exercise does not explicitly require $K\neq\emptyset$, but I guess it is implied. Could you elaborate more?

You define the partial ordering on $\mathcal F$ by containment. The punchline is that the maximal (or minimal in this case) element must be a set on $\mathcal F$, so if $\varnothing\in\mathcal F$ then of course you're done, since that's a minimal element for any collection, but if it's not, then you're guaranteed that your minimal element is non empty. The main idea is, show that any intersection of that form can be written as a countable intersection (equivalently show that unions of opens can be written as countable unions) and then you're done

I'm gonna turn my comment from yesterday into an actual proof. To answer your question about it being related to Brouwer's theorem, I don't know, such a proof would be very contrived, since Brouwer's fixed point theorem only applies in Euclidean spaces.
Now, for the actual proof, we'll start proving the following lemma.

Lemma. Let $\{C_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be a collection of closed sets, then, there exists a countable $\Lambda'\subset\Lambda$, such that
$$\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda'}C_\lambda=\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}C_\lambda$$
Proof. By taking complements, it's enough to show that if $\{U_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be a collection of open sets, then, there exists a countable $\Lambda'\subset\Lambda$, such that
$$\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda'}U_\lambda=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_\lambda$$
Let $\{B_i\}_{i\geq 1}$ be the elements of a countable base such that they are contained some $U_\lambda$ and let $\{B_{\lambda(i)}\}_{i\geq 1}$ be the elements of the base that are contained in $U_\lambda$. Notice that
$$\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_\lambda=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}\bigcup_{i\geq 1}B_{\lambda(i)}=\bigcup_{i\geq 1}B_i$$
on the other hand, for each $i\geq 1$ choose a $\lambda\in\Lambda$ such that $B_i\subset U_\lambda$ which we know exists by definition of $\{B_i\}_{i\geq1}$ (we're implicitly using AC), and let $\Lambda'$ be the collection of the chosen $\lambda$'s, which is countable, since it's the image of a countable set. Now
$$\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda'}U_\lambda=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda'}\bigcup_{i\geq 1}B_{\lambda(i)}=\bigcup_{i\geq 1}B_i$$
therefore
$$\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda'}U_\lambda=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}U_\lambda$$

using this, let $\{K_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be a chain in $\mathcal F$ under the supset ordering. It's clear that if $\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}K_\lambda\in\mathcal F$ then this is an upper bound. Now, let $\Lambda'\subset\Lambda$ as in the lemma, then
$$\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda}K_\lambda=\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda'}K_\lambda$$
now, let $\lambda(i)$ for $i\in\mathbb{Z}$ be an ordering such that $K_{\lambda(i)}\supset K_{\lambda(i+1)}$ for every $i$, then
$$\bigcap_{\lambda\in\Lambda'}K_\lambda=\bigcap_{i\in \mathbb Z}K_{\lambda(i)}=\bigcap_{i\geq 1}K_{\lambda(i)}$$
sice they're nested. Now, by hypothesis, this is an element of $\mathcal F$. Thereforem every chain has an upper bound; therefore, by Zorn's lemma, there's a maximal element, since a maximal element under the supset ordering is a minimal element under the subset ordering; this is the minimal element we're looking for.
I wanted to address something you mentioned on your question. $\varnothing$ is not trivially a minimal element, because for it to be a minimal element you should have $\varnothing\in\mathcal F$, if you knew that, then it is of course a minimal element, otherwise, for all other families $\mathcal F\not\ni\varnothing$ that satisfy that intersection property, $\varnothing$ is not a minimal element, since you need a minimal element to be part of your partial ordering; and I'm only partially ordering the elements in $\mathcal F$

Thanks! I had never seen this proof. I kind of got a general feeling with your last comment, but, honestly, there is nothing like a clearly laid out proof! This is simply beautiful! Also, you were the reason I used Zorn's lemma for the first time!

@Janis I'm glad I could help!
